# ms sql database and C# OOP interaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop

If I need to work with data from ms SQL server database it's comfortable to use queries. But then I don't need classes and objects to store data, which means that I'm not using OOP (object orientated programming) principles. 
What is a sensible thing to do?

Comment: How does it mean you aren't using an OOP approach? OOP also means re-usable methods, so you can have a method which retrieves specific details from your DB according to an ID..

Comment: a `sensible thing to do`, in your case is for starters `1. Make more sense` `.2 understand the who, what where && how` to connect to a database to return records and or how to execute querys , `Fill` data in C# Data Objects etc..

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use classes to organize the data from the form? Otherwise, you may end up with procedural spaghetti code possibly.

Comment: Hm, [go](http://www.golang.org) might be worth a shot. @JBKing OOP isn't the only way of organizing code, and procedural design does not necessarily lead to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to do such an app, and only ever use HTML for example, but by the looks of it, you would require to execute TONS of SQL calls all the time, to set and access your variables, instead of using the built in functionality of OOP. Purely from an app's speed point of view it would be quite slow and taxing to your servers. It might work for a single user, but anything commercial would kill your servers almost immediately. 
From security point of view, every call is a potential risk, and running 100 calls a second would make it quite easy to sniff any data I'd like to see.

Sensible is use classes and variables and run stored procedures instead of simple SQL queries- vulnerable to injections